# Best Strategy to Copy delta from one database to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have  a Transaction Database TD with Table A.
  I have another Reporting Database RD with Table B.
  Table B is exactly similar to table A in terms of Columns & Datatypes.

**I need to copy Table A into Table B** :

Specifics about Table A :
1)Table A is a transaction table and there are new transactions added everyday into it.
2)Also Table A has updates to existing transactions every day, there is a column called **updateddate** which is updated in case there are any updates on the transaction.

**Method I am following :**
   I created an SSIS package to copy the data from Transaction Database to Reporting 
   Database the first time, In table **B** I created a new column called **RDUpdateddate** to insert the time each record was updated.

I created another SSIS package which I set up as a SqlServerJob running everynight.
   It gets all the transactions that were run after the **RDUpdateddate** and copys them 
   to a staging table. Then I use a stored procedure to insert and update my table B.

Although this method works.I would like to know if there is a more efficient way of doing everything in the SSIS package itself

Comment: If I understand correctly, you already have a solution that works using 2 SSIS packages. But you want it to be "more efficient"; what does that mean for you and what problem are you trying to solve? Should it run faster, or use less RAM or CPU, or be easier to configure or something else? If you can explain exactly what is wrong with your current solution then someone may have an alternative.

Comment: Yes I have a solution, but I need 2 SSIS packages, a staging table and an additional stored procedure to accomplish my task. I wanted to know if there is a way to accomplish the task within a single SSIS task , or any other simpler method.

Comment: Using multiple packages, staging tables and stored procedures sounds like a typical ETL implementation to me, so unless you have a specific problem I would just use what you have. Many ETL tasks are easier to do outside SSIS but you can still use a package to control the workflow and call other processes using Execute SQL, Execute Process and Script tasks.

Answer (score 2):

What I normally do for this cases is something like this:
[image]

If I understand well what you're doing, you can't identify if a register change without using the field **RDUpdateddate** that you created in Table B, *if you want to change that, but I really don't think is good idea, you can use a hash field in each table, just add it the the query not fisically in the table, it must be updated each time you execute the package*.

After that is the join having as left table the Table A to obtain if the register is new or old, you identify that by using one field of Table B, if the field is null is beacuse it doesn't exist.

In the conditional split you should use the column of the Table B to know if is knew, and your're prefered method to update if it already exists.

**Edit:**

To be able to compare the two tables you can create a query like this in Table A:

```
SELECT id, field1, field2, CHECKSUM(field1, field2) HASH_TOTAL FROM Table_A
```

And a query like this in Table B:

```
SELECT id, field1, field2, CHECKSUM(field1, field2) HASH_TOTAL FROM Table_B
```

Then in the Conditional Split you evalute if the values are equal, different or doesn't exist the value in table B.

---

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Rednaxel ! Thank you very much for the illustration. I am looking at something like this. If you dont mind , I have a question on your example.Do you mean that instead of RDUpdateddate , I can use a hash field in each table of Table B .Each time the package updates the table ,would the hash field change? Could you tell me how I can create the hash field ? or point me out to any resource online on how that would work ?

Comment: I'm changing my answer to add an explanation of hash compare